# How to Show App banner on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

I have an iOS or Android app we would want to show installation banner when users visit your website via mobile browser.

I try to use this plugin :

https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Google, Inc.">
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=544007664">
    <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.google.android.youtube">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.smartbanner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.smartbanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() { $.smartbanner() } )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need when any user install my app. show view icon ,But if user not install it , show him download

How can do that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please first read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so we can help you.

Comment: Also please show us what you've tried so far. You cannot assume that we do your work.

Comment: see my post,, i add all my code and explain what i need